# Java API to create UML diagrams

Tags: java, uml

Is there any Java API (Opensource) that can be used in drawing/creating UML diagrams.

JFreeChart is a Java API to draw charts/bars/graphs, similarly is there any tool to draw UML diagrams using Java ?

Comment: I won't provide this as an answer, as I don't know how feasible it would be.  There is ArgoUML which is an open source tool in Java for creating diagrams.  It is open source, and with a quick glance, there appears to be various classes to create the various diagrams..this might be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, I can go through its source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not specifically for UML diagrams but I have been using [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) to create hierarchical graphs and am very happy with it. Take a look at the [examples](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/index.html) they have and see if it's useful for you.

Comment: That helps, but I will wait to see If I can get even better/powerful APIs

Comment: ok, no problem. btw do you intend on creating UMLs of your own Java code, or having the possibility of providing the user with UML graphs at runtime?

Comment: I have some info which I need to display using UML diagrams. I should have the possibility to structure it the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create class diagrams, [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-Draw2d/GEF-Draw2d.html) shows how to do it with eclipse draw2d.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [EMF-based implementation of the UMLTM 2.4.1 metamodel](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2#Javadoc) for the Eclipse platform.

This will allow you to create the UML diagrams. Then you could use any EMF-UML compatible tool to visualize them

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing and then I found about this open source project called [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/sequence.html). They have some good example and pretty much cover everything that you may have wanted.